# Time series : Contradiction between ADF test and decomposition using STL

Tags: r

I have a time series. I performed ADF test (dickey fuller) and it was non stationary. I performed differencing with lag 1 and checked the stationarity using Dickey fuller test...The ADF test showed that there is stationarity now in data after differencing but when I decompose the time series using STL, Im still getting seasonality ...The trend is gone now but seasonality remains...Can a stationary series have strong seasonality?

```
 ts
    Jan   Feb   Mar   Apr   May   Jun   Jul   Aug    Sep   Oct   Nov   Dec
2013 23770 23482 23601 22889 23401 24240 23873 23647  23378 23871 22624 23496
2014 26765 27619 26341 27320 27389 27418 26874 27005  27538 26324 27267 27583
2015 28354 27452 28336 28998 28595 28338 27806 28660  27226 28317 28666 28574
2016 30209 30659 31554 30248 30358 31091 30389 30247 31227 31839 30602 30609
2017 32180 32203 31639 31784 32375 30856 31863 32827 32506 31702 31681 32176
```

Decomposition plot before differencing

```
decomp <- stl(ts,s.window = "periodic")
plot(decomp)
```

[image]

Decomposition plot after differencing with lag = 1.

```
diff_1<-(diff(ts,lag=1, k=7))
decomp_diff1 <- stl(diff_1,s.window = "periodic")
plot(decomp_diff1)
```

[image]

As can be seen, that in second image after differencing too, there is seasonality, but Dickey fuller's test shows stationary data. How is that possible?

```
adf.test(diff(ts_actual_group2,lag=1, k=7))
data:  diff(ts_actual_group2, lag = 1, k = 7)
Dickey-Fuller = -3.9676, Lag order = 3, p-value =
0.01719
alternative hypothesis: stationary
```

Comment: wool mitten sales in July?

Comment: No. some other dataset